# What code is responding when WebAPI responds to a request such as http://server/vroot/odata?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

What specifically in WebAPI responds to:

```
1. http://server/vroot/odata  
2. http://server/vroot/odata?$metadata
3. http://server/vroot/odata/Foo
```

When #3 is requested, I understand that my 'FooController' responds as
configured in my WebApiConfig.cs.

But it is not clear to me how WebAPI responds to #1 or #2.  How does it know
what to return?  How is that response configured in my code?

> UPDATE: Here is a HUGE clue
>
> From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/01/29/getting-started-with-asp-net-webapi-odata-in-3-simple-steps.aspx
>
> One important thing to realize here is that the controller name, the
>   action names, and the parameter names all matter. OData controller and
>   action selection work a little differently than they do in Web API.
>   Instead of being based on route parameters, OData controller and
>   action selection is based on the OData meaning of the request URI. So
>   for example if you made a request for
>   http://my.server.com/vroot/odata/$metadata, the request would actually get
>   dispatched to a separate special controller that returns the metadata
>   document for the OData service. Notice how the controller name also
>   matches the entity set name we defined previously. I’ll try to go into
>   more depth about OData routing in a future blog post.
>   ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. returns you the `Service Document`
2. returns you the `Service Metadata Document`

WebAPI knows this because you add a route similar to `config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);`

Check out this detailed explanation: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/creating-an-odata-endpoint

Comment: So, its all internal to WebAPI?

Comment: Thanks for that link.  It helped me realize that the question I should have asked is: What controller serves up the "Service Document"? Answer: ODataMetadataController